# How can I prioritize concrete web.api url routing above abstract url routing

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes

I have two controllers.  To Web.API, the attribute routes I've set up are the same, but one has a concrete value while the other is tokenized.  Lemme 'splain.

The first I'd like to match when the Url is http://localhost/MemberProfile.  So, I add a MemberProfileController and place this at the top:

```
[Route("api/MemberProfile/{id:guid?}", Order = 0)]
public class MemberProfileController : ApiController
```

I then have abstract routes I'd like to match so that the Url http://localhost/City matches the DefaultController which has this at the top:

```
[Route("api/{type}/{id:guid?}", Order = 1)]
public class DefaultController : ApiController
```

I've left Order in there to show that I've considered that options, but it only applies to actions within the same controller.  I would love the concrete value of MemberProfile to match the first route while any other value matches the tokenized Route.  Instead, when I hit http://localhost/MemberProfile, I get a warning that says:

```
Multiple controller types were found that match the URL.
```

Because that matches both `api/MemberProfile` and `api/{type}` I get it.  It makes sense, but I would love for the concrete value to take precedence.  Is there any way to accomplish this?  Is there a way to use the old style of setting up the routing table in the config to give one or the other priority without losing all of the web api action matching magic based on request type and params?

Comment: Create a custom route constraint and apply it to the `{type}` that does not allow a match when the value is `MemberProfile`

Comment: I'm not sure this is as scalable and manageable as I would need it to be, but it is an option.  =]

Answer (score 0):

Attribute routing trumps WebApiConfig routing, which means that any routes that you set up in the routing table by adding them in WebApiConfig.cs `Register()` method will be second priority to any routes that you set up via attribute routing.  In this case, if you set up a routing table entry in the WebApiConfig that matches your tokenized routes like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{type}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "DefaultController", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

You'll have your matching for unknown {type} urls such as http://localhost/City.  This will route any request to your DefaultController and Web API will pick up the routing from there using request verb and parameter matching as normal.  Then, in your MemberProfileController, set it up just as shown in the question:

```
[Route("api/MemberProfile/{id:guid?}", Order = 0)]
public class MemberProfileController : ApiController
```

This will now take precedence over the route set up in the WebApiConfig.cs `Register()` method and http://localhost/MemberProfile will be routed to the MemberProfile controller but let everything else that matches the route format fall through to your DefaultController.